# Starting MongoDB v3.2.10 on startup on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04, autostart

I have set up a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 server on a VirtualBox VM. The only other custom application I have installed in NginX. I want to get MongoDB to launch automatically when the server reboots.

The official [MongoDB installation page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#ubuntu-16-04-only-create-systemd-service-file) that I have been following tells me to create a file at `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`, with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, this file already existed, with more entries, so I did not touch it.

The [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-2-%E2%80%94-installing-and-verifying-mongodb) tells me to create a file with almost the same contents at `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` (`etc` not `lib` and `mongodb` rather than `mongod`; Documentation and Group are missing). This tutorial also suggests using...

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb
```

... "to enable automatically starting MongoDB when the system starts". But I get this error:

```
Failed to execute operation: Invalid argument
```

I have tried both techniques, but when I reboot the server, MongoDB does not start.

I've also seen a mention of a [tool to create an init script](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/stop-using-automation/#the-make-init-scripts-tool) at `/opt/mongodb-mms-automation/bin/mongodb-mms-automation-make-init-scripts`, but this was not installed when I followed the [instructions on the MongoDB site](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message isn't very helpful but `sudo journalctl -f -n 200` will give you some  insight into what might go wrong.

Do you have the `mongodb` user and group on your system?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about `journaltcl`. It told me `systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service:1] Missing '='.` which allowed me to discover that the first three characters in the file had somehow been deleted. I restored them, saved the file, rebooted, and MongoDB is now happily running.